# Image not displaying - xamarin emdeded resource Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, embedded-resource

I'm following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images) example of using images as embedded resources.

I've set the image as an embedded resource, added the extension and the reference to it in XAML, used the full path(using a dot as a separator)  but the image is not displayed. I've set a breakpoint in the extension and it gets hit.
Both the code and the XAML are equivalent to the linked example (only the path to the image is different).

I get the following error in the output window:
ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue while following the same tutorial. Luckily debugging helped to solve my issue, maybe it might help you as well.

Having the error: "ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource" I decided to have a look to the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/StreamImagesourceHandler.cs) for that.

It prints this error only in the circumstances when bitmap is null.
But wait. I know that my bitmap is not null so the problem must lie in between - the path must be incorrect.
Using the debugging code that they posted in the same article, invoked in the constructor:

```
private void CheckResourcesFound()
{
  // ...
  // NOTE: use for debugging, not in released app code!
  var assembly = typeof(<class-name-this-method-is-in>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
  }
}
```

I have noticed what @pnet already pointed out - the path needs to be constructed in this way

```
<assembly>.<folders-separated-by-dot>.<resource-with-extension>
```

My pic was in Resource dir. Assuming yours is as well then your xaml should look like:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource 'projectname.Resources.imagename.png'}" .../>
```

After adjusting and compiling and finally running I eventually could see the pic I wanted in my app :)

Answer (score 0):

you must to create a converter as this:

```
[ContentProperty ("Source")]
        public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
        {
         public string Source { get; set; }

         public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
         {
           if (Source == null)
           {
             return null;
           }
           // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
           var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

           return imageSource;
         }
        }
```

and here your UI

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:projectname;assembly=projectname"

<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="MainLayout">
            <Image Source="{local:ImageResource projectname.imagename.png}"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I hope help you.

**EDIT1**

With me is working. See the screenshot

[image]

My xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"
             x:Class="Operacional.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="Layout">

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image  Source="{local:ImageResource Operacional.Images.automotive.png}"></Image>
                <local:Badge x:Name="OcupacaoNotifications" BoxColor="Red"
                             WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="18" 
                             VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Double>30</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>10</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </local:Badge>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

My class

```
[ContentProperty("Source")]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
```

With this code i got to see the image above

`<Image  Source="{local:ImageResource Operacional.Images.automotive.png}">`

> NameSpace.FolderName.ImageName.extension

Comment: This is looks like what i did initially. I copied your code and it still doesn't work. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: {System.Reflection.TargetException: Exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' was thrown.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.ThrowNoInvokeException()

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this example, trying to get it to work in my code, with no luck. Until I realized the example wasn't using a shared project, and the assembly name for each platform's app is different, so the XAML can't find it and include the ImageResourceExtension. I renamed the output assembly in both platform projects, and it worked.

Took me several hours to find that nugget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need answers to this after 4 years but you probably forgot to set the image `Build Action` to `Embedded resource`.

In VS 2022 you do this by clicking on the image in the Solution Explorer. In the
`Build Action` property you select `Embedded resource`.